# login local with jquery ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, json, session

I want make a file that on click opens in Google Chrome. It loads a JavaScript file from my server into the head and sends the token from `index.html` (local) to my server.

But when I `print_r($_SESSION)` the array is empty.

**`index.html` (this file is on the computer)**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="nl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.site.com/main/plugin/1.9.2_jquery-ui.css" />
                <script src="http://www.site.com/main/plugin/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
                <script src="http://www.site.com/main/plugin/1.9.2_jquery-ui.js"></script>
                <script src="http://www.site.com/login/token.js"></script>
        <script>
            var token = 'test';
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Indien deze tekst blijft staan is er geen verbinding met de server.
    </body>
</html>
```

**`www.site.com/login/token.js`**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').html('<div># Jquery geladen, verbonden met server</div>');

    $('body').append('<div># Inloggen...</div>');
    var adapter = "http://www.site.com/login/token.php";
    $.getJSON( adapter, {
            token: token
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        if(data.error == 'NULL') {
            if(data.message !== 'NULL') {
                $('body').append('<div># ' + data.message + '.</div>');
                alert(data.message);
            }

            if(data.login == 'true') {
                $('body').append('<div># Inloggen gelukt.</div>');
                $('body').append('<div># Opstarten...</div>');
                window.location.replace("http://www.site.com");    
            } else {
                $('body').append('<div style="background:rgb(255, 187, 187)"># Inloggen mislukt.</div>');
            }        
        } else {
            $('body').append('<div style="background:rgb(255, 187, 187)"># ' + data.error + '</div>');
            alert(data.error);
        }
    })
    .fail(function() {
        $('body').append('<div style="background:rgb(255, 187, 187)"># Er is een fout opgetreden bij het inloggen.</div>');
        alert('Er is een fout opgetreden bij het inloggen.');
    });
});
```

**`index.php`**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include "../main/instellingen.php";

    $data_output = array();
    $data_output['error'] = 'NULL';
    $data_output['message'] = 'NULL';
    $data_output['login'] = 'false';

    print_r($_SESSION);
    /*=== controleer is er al ingelogd ===*/
    if(!isset($_SESSION['gebruikersnaam'])) {
        if(!empty($_GET['token'])) {
            /*controleer inloghack*/
        } else {
            $data_output['error'] = 'Niet alle gegevens zijn ingevoerd.';
        }
    } else {
        $data_output['message'] = 'U bent al ingelogd.';
        $data_output['login'] = 'true';
    }
    /*=== output ===*/
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
        echo json_encode($data_output);    
?>
```

Comment: Where are you setting `$_SESSION['gebruikersnaam']` sessions wont work with .html

Comment: the js file and the php file are on the server, the html file is local. The php file is the only thing that must read the session and send back if the session is set.

Comment: sorry what I was getting at was that `print_r($_SESSION);` is going to be empty if your not setting any session variables.

Comment: but wen i login on the main site (form) i have then 4 sessions but none of them are showing on the token.php file